# ScreenSnap not working anymore under Windows 10

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

There seems to be an issue with the `TForm.ScreenSnap` property on Windows 10.

I always have `ScreenSnap` active for Main Forms, and the `SnapBuffer` set to 10 pixels. This works fine until Windows 10.

Now, if `ScreenSnap` is active, the Form will stick to the screen edge as it is supposed to do. But, if I want to un-stick it, I have to move the window vigorously. If I move the mouse too slow, the Form will remain stuck to the screen border, resulting in a very weird user experience.

Does anyone know how to fix this (without disabling `ScreenSnap` on Windows 10)?  Or, at least, can anyone else confirm this as a bug?

Comment: Err, does ScreenSnap work under FPC + Lazarus?

Comment: @AlexJames FPC does not have `ScreenSnap`, that is a feature of Delphi: [`TForm.ScreenSnap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.ScreenSnap)

Comment: This appear to be a known bug: [RSP-27155: Cannot be release from the screen edge when ScreenSnap is enabled](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27155).  Seems to be DPI-related, as the ticket poster says: "*If you change the Project-DPI setting to something other than PerMonitorV2, ScreenSnap will work properly.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau, exactly, it was an ironic q.

Comment: temporary "fix": Set SnapBuffer to a small value (like 3) and the bug will be less visible.

Comment: @InTheNameOfScience There is a huge difference between 3 and 4. 3 works OK but 4 behaves like default 10. Any idea why?

Comment: @Andrzej - Remy Lebeau provided an explanation for that: unfortunately, it's a (unfixed) Delphi bug. Wait until they release an edition that fixes the bug and update your license. Under the new licensing scheme you will only get bug fixes for one year. I like how they added a looooooooooooooong time awaited feature (High DPI support) just to break with that another feature.